# How can I fix the Foreach array in array in php to return the result

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-blade

Data from Api after request

```
array:1 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "name" => "test"
  "active_domain" => "https://drycleaner.com"
  "domains" => array:1 [▶]
  "rr" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "end_at" => "2020-11-08T08:00:00.000+08:00"
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "end_at" => "2020-11-08T08:00:00.000+08:00"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

php laravel blade.view

```
@foreach ($store["rr"] as $key2=>$rr){
     @foreach ($rr["rss"] as key3 =>$rss)}
        <td>{{ date("d-M-y  H:i", strtotime($rss["end_at"])) }}</td>
          @endforeach
```

Undefined end_at error. I think it's a problem with the foreach column naming. How can I grab from api which is "end_at" and insert into the table.

Comment: where does key dssl appear? Not showing in your array output

Comment: Ever heard of array_combine? I think you should use that. And as other commenter stated, where does "dssl" appear?

Answer (score 0):

`end_at` key is on second array of `$dr`. You need to call foreach again or use key directly like `$dssl[0]["end_at"]`:

```
<td>{{ date("d-M-y  H:i", strtotime($dssl[0]["end_at"])) }}</td>
```

or using foreach

```
@foreach ($store["dr"] as $key2=>$dr){
     @foreach ($dr["dssl"] as key3 =>$dssl)}
          @foreach ($dssl as key4 =>$dss)}
        <td>{{ date("d-M-y  H:i", strtotime($dss["end_at"])) }}</td>
          @endforeach
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: i think there is one missing curly bracket.

Comment: I think it's correct, which code you copied?

Comment: now its saying undefined index: dssl, any idea?

Comment: the second one.

Comment: you didnt copy corectly. try to show me your current  code in your post

Comment: why the array is different? what is your current error?

Comment: i've edited it. its just a little different. thats the dd() output from laravel

Answer (score 0):

in the blade syntax you have to close every foreach :

```
@foreach ($store["dr"] as $key2=>$dr){
    @foreach ($dr as key3 =>$dssl)}
        <td>{{ date("d-M-y  H:i", strtotime($dssl["end_at"])) }}</td>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```